# Domain migration and duplicate content/index issue

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, google-index

I have a `website.net` which I want to 301 redirect to `website.com` and I also want to change URL structure on some pages on the new `.com` site.

Problem is that `.com` is currently set as *Website Alias* of `.net` version, which means that there are same pages indexed in Google from both domains.

I could 301 `.net` to `.com` and then after a while 301 new URLs on `.com` and update old `.net` redirects at the same time but that would take too long time, given I would have to wait in between for Google to update everything.

Is there a better and faster solution to this, which is still in line with Google recommendations when migrating domains?

Answer (score 1):

Search engines have no problem following a chain of 301 redirects, so I don't see why you can't just make all the changes at once.

Some things you can do to [speed up the canonicalization process](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139066) are:

- Specify the canonical link for each page in the HTML `<head>` and/or in the HTTP headers (the former is preferred)
- Use a [sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=40318) which contains only the canonical URLs

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to update the Google index is to submit your changes in the Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to [use 301 redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) to remove all duplicate content. However, if you do a blanket `301 redirect` from *example.net* to *example.com* you're telling the search engines that you are no longer going to use *example.net* for anything because you are ***permanently redirecting*** all content to the *.com* domain.

If you want to maintain the `.net` domain for the content that is not duplicated, then you should use single 301 redirects for all content which belongs on the *.com* domain.

One method, if you're using Apache is to perform these at the `.htaccess` level (so web designers and developers can edit them).

An example directive found in the *example.net* site would then look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(folder/topic-1.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old-folder/(topic-2.*) http://www.example.com/new-folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you're not concerned with who has access to what, then [you can use RewriteMaps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) as well. They need to be entered directly into the Virtual Host declarations in the configuration files for the server, but the map can be editable at a level accessible to users with `SSH` or `FTP`(`SFTP is better`) access (outside of the document root).

If you're using dynamic files in a language like PHP, then you can replace the file people are expecting with a 301 redirect in the code:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: http://www.example.com/new-folder/topic-2/');
?>
```

[Redirects in other languages can be found here](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php).